# youtube_dl - Overwritting metadata

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I have managed to extract the title and artist using the --metadata-from-title option, but it seems that it does not overwrite if those metadata items already exist in the video file.

I'm am using:

```
py -3 -m youtube_dl -o "%(title)s.%(ext)s" -x --audio-format mp3 --audio-quality 320K --embed-thumbnail --add-metadata --metadata-from-title "%(artist)s ~ %(title)s" oLNMnOYEMAA
```

Is this is a bug?

If not then is it possible to overwrite the existing values?  I know that you can do it using the postprocessor-args command, but do not know if it is possible to pass the title and artist as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

From the [youtube-dl github](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#installation)

> `--metadata-from-title`
>
> > ...Parse additional metadata like song title /
> >                                      artist from the video title...

The keyword being additional metadata, it's not supposed to remove or replace the existing just add the additional data if possible.

I also looked through the known bugs and this was *not* one of them.

Comment: It's probably not clear that there are two parts of the question and that is whether I can pass the information from the --metadata-from-title forward to the postprocessor-args command.  

In the end I wrote a separate python program using the mutagen package to update the tags.  Once I tidy it up, I'll upload it.